# User is not being created for ruby on rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my ruby on the rails server running and I found this weird error that hard for me to debug because there is less information about the problem is given on the rails console.
There is something wrong with the /users route. which is responsible for creating a new user. I am using doorkeeper with JWT to authenticate users in my application. here is the code for the registration controller.

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  skip_before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!

  # POST /resource
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user.present?
      render json: { success: false }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    else
      new_user = User.new
      new_user.email = params[:email]
      new_user.name = params[:name]
      new_user.password = params[:password]
      new_user.organization_id = Organization.first.id
      new_user.level_id = Level.first.id
      new_user.token = SecureRandom.hex(10)
      if new_user.save(validate: false)
        render json: { success: true }, status: :ok
      else
        render json: { success: false}, status: :ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and here is the response that I am getting in my console on a post request from Postman.
[console error with code 302](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvHyZ.png)

my routes function for /users looks something like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users
      post 'oauth/token', to: 'oauth/access_tokens#create'
      use_doorkeeper
      get 'doorkeeper/new_oauth_application', to: 'doorkeeper/applications#new', as: :new_oauth_application
      get 'doorkeeper/edit_oauth_application/:id', to: 'doorkeeper/applications#edit', as: :edit_oauth_application
      get 'badge/:id', to: 'v1/badges#show', as: :show_badge
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :badges, only: %i[index]
        resources :categories, only: %i[index show] do
          member do
            post :answer
          end
        end
        resources :charges, only: %i[create index show] do
          get :cancel
        end
        resources :carbon_offsets, only: %i[index show] do
          member do
            post :purchase
          end
        end
        resources :carbon_offset_projects, only: %i[index show]
        resources :habits, only: %i[index show] do
          collection do
            get :today
          end
          member do
            post :complete
          end
        end
        resources :reductions do
          collection do
            get 'between/:start/:end', to: 'reductions#between', as: :reductions_between
          end
        end
        resources :products, only: %i[index show create] do
          collection do
            post :preview
          end
        end
        resources :questions, only: %i[index show] do
          member do
            post :answer
          end
        end
        resources :reactions
        resources :resources, only: %i[index show create] do
          collection do
            post :preview
          end
        end
        resources :users, only: %(show) do
          member do
            post :follow
            delete :follow
          end
        end
        resources :shares, only: %i[index]
        resources :tags, only: %i[index show]
        post 'change_password', to: 'user#change_password', as: :change_password
        get 'change_password', to: 'user#change_password_authenticated'
        scope :community do
          get 'local', to: 'community#local', as: :community_local
          get 'peers', to: 'community#peers', as: :community_peers
          get 'active', to: 'community#active', as: :community_active
          get 'facebook', to: 'community#facebook', as: :community_facebook
          get 'followers', to: 'community#followers', as: :community_followers
          get 'following', to: 'community#following', as: :community_following
          get 'unread_count', to: 'community#unread_count', as: :community_unread_count
          post 'status_update', to: 'community#status_update', as: :status_update
          post 'reaction', to: 'community#add_reaction', as: :add_reaction
          post 'notify', to: 'community#notify', as: :notify
        end
        scope :my do
          get 'account', to: 'user#info', as: :account_info
          post 'account', to: 'user#update', as: :account_update
          put 'fcm_token', to: 'user#update_fcm_token', as: :fcm_token_update
          delete 'account', to: 'user#delete', as: :account_delete
          post 'account/send-verification-email', to: 'user#send_verification_email'
          get 'impact', to: 'user#impact', as: :my_impact
          get 'recommendations', to: 'user#recommendations', as: :recommendations
          get 'friend/:id', to: 'user#userinfo_by_facebook_id', as: :userinfo_by_facebook_id
        end
        scope :custom do
          get 'pg', to: 'custom#pg', as: :pg
        end
      end
    
      root to: redirect('http://localhost:3000')
    
    end
```

I am using postgresql as database with rails and also using redis for caching data.

Any help here would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It's better avoid posting screen shots of code or logs, because it people can't search for similar errors and generally makes it harder to help you. Check out the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037979/how-to-prevent-devise-from-issuing-a-302-redirect-using-ajax), which might be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Devise from issuing a 302 redirect using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037979/how-to-prevent-devise-from-issuing-a-302-redirect-using-ajax)

Comment: @Eyeslandic No, it doesn't I believe It could have some issue with routing I have given my routes.rb file's function that handles /users routes above. if it's helpful.